# Why we can't make materialized view on top of another view in clickhouse?

Tags: clickhouse

A is a collapsingMergeTree engine table

CREATE VIEW A AS SELECT * FROM A final;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW a_mview1 TO B 
AS select id, 
name
from  A;

This is not working it seems we can't make mview on view..but why?

Answer (score 1):

**Normal** View doesn't store any data (see [doc](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/create/#create-view)) so that it is wrong to use it as a source of data for **Materialized** View.

It needs to create Materialized View based on the origin table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE A (
  ..
) ENGINE = CollapsingMergeTree
.. ;

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW a_mview1 TO B 
AS 
SELECT ..
FROM A
.. ;
```

Look at the article [ClickHouse Materialized Views Illuminated](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-materialized-views-illuminated-part-1) for details.

Answer (score 1):

> CREATE VIEW A AS SELECT * FROM A final;

It's impossible. Because MV never reads a source table. MV gets inserted blocks from INSERT command.